# Random polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want do draw some random tiny circles inside a bigger one.

I use `rnd` at both coordinates (polar): `({30*rnd}:{2*rnd})` -- here I want to have tiny circles in the range [0;30] degrees. The ouput is random but not limited to 30 degrees.

Then I want a constant angle: `({30}:{2*rnd})`. The output doesn't make any sense. Both coordinates are random.

Finally I want constant distance to the center: `({30*rnd}:{2})`. Everything OK by the looks of it: it's an arc limited by the 30 degrees.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc, positioning}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3);

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (30:3);
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000};
\foreach \iter in {1,2,...,50} {
    \draw[fill=red] ({30*rnd}:{2*rnd}) circle(0.01);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3);

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (30:3);
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000};
\foreach \iter in {1,2,...,50} {
    \draw[fill=red] ({30}:{2*rnd}) circle(0.01);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3);

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (30:3);
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000};
\foreach \iter in {1,2,...,50} {
    \draw[fill=red] ({30*rnd}:{2}) circle(0.01);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polar coordinates in TikZ can be specified using a single radius for a circular coordinate system, or using an x and a y radius for elliptical coordinate systems. Internally, the circular coordinate system is represented by an elliptical coordinate system with `x radius = y radius`. This works fine for static values, but if the radius is set to `rnd`, different random numbers are generated for the `x radius` and the `y radius`, resulting in the behaviour you observed.

You can work around this by calculating the random radius outside the `\draw` statement using `\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{1+rnd}`, and then using `\radius` in the coordinate specification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3);
\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (30:3);
\pgfmathsetseed{1};
\foreach \iter in {1,2,...,50} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\radius{1+rnd}
    \draw[fill=red] (rnd*30:\radius) circle(0.01);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3);

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (30:3);
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000};
\foreach \iter in {1,2,...,50} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\radius{2*rnd}
    \draw[fill=red] ({30}:{\radius}) circle(0.01);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle(3);

\draw[dashed] (0:0) -- (30:3);
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 1000000};
\foreach \iter in {1,2,...,50} {
    \draw[fill=red] ({30*rnd}:{2}) circle(0.01);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it definitely looks like a bug :) but I'm new to tikz so I didn't risk the assumption in first place :) thank you!

Comment: @maf: I figured out why this happens! I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: or  `\pgfmathresult`  directly

Comment: @percusse: Yes!

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks (no bug):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}
\SpecialCoor

\begin{document}
% case 1: random radius [0,2] unit and angle [0,30] degrees
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){3}
    \psLoop{50}{\pscircle(!rand 201 mod 100 div rand 301 mod 10 div PtoC){.01}}
\end{pspicture}

% case 2: random radius [0,2] unit and fixed angle 30 degrees
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){3}
    \psLoop{50}{\pscircle(!rand 201 mod 100 div 30 PtoC){.01}}
\end{pspicture}

% case 3: fixed radius 2 unit and random angle [0,30] degrees
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle(0,0){3}
    \psLoop{50}{\pscircle(!2 rand 301 mod 10 div PtoC){.01}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Outputs:

- Both radius and angle are randomly specified

  [image]
- Random radius and fixed angle

  [image]
- Fixed radius and random angle

  [image]

Comment: As the radius of the small circle is too small, it is better to use `\qdisk`  instead of `\pscircle`.