# Concat segmental region into one region

Tags: tikz-pgf, lattice

I'm looking for a way to concat a segmental regions into one region that overlap each other like this one:
[image]

For the gray region on the left picture, i have generated a pentagon from this question answer: [Creating random patterns in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130555/creating-random-patterns-in-tikz). But how can i concat those region into one region like the right picture and still keep the distance?
This is from BLICHFELD's theorem in [https://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/introduction.pdf](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/introduction.pdf)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
        \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
        \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-3,0);
        \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (10,0);
        \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2);
        \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,10);
        
        \draw [thin, black,-latex] (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);% Draw x axis
        \draw [thin, black,-latex] (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);% Draw y axis
        
        \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8cm,4cm);
        \coordinate (Bone) at (0,2);
        \coordinate (Btwo) at (4,2);
        %\coordinate (Bthree) at (2, 4);
        \draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-14,-14) grid[step=2cm] (14,14);
        
       \foreach \x in {-7,-6,...,7}{% Two indices running over each
            \foreach \y in {-7,-6,...,7}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
                \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (4*\x, 4*\x + 2*\y) {};
                    % Places a dot at those points
            }
        }
            
        %\draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
        %    -- (Bthree) node [above, right] {$b_3$};
        \fill[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.3, draw=black] (4,2) ellipse (3cm and 1.75cm);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you maybe provide the code for this drawing? It will be easier to help you then.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have edit the post so it include my image on the left but i can't find the code for the drawing of the pdf because it is in a paper and i want to recreate it.

Comment: I would do this by drawing the region times shifted so that different quadrants overlap as desired and then use `\clip` to keep only the quadrant with the overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably needs some refinement, but you could maybe make use of the `spy` library:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45, spy using overlays={black!0, height={0.45*2cm}, width={0.45*4cm}, anchor=south west}]
    \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-3,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (10,0);
    \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2);
    \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,10);
    
    \draw [thin, black,-latex] (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);% Draw x axis
    \draw [thin, black,-latex] (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);% Draw y axis
    
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8cm,4cm);
    \coordinate (Bone) at (0,2);
    \coordinate (Btwo) at (4,2);
    %\coordinate (Bthree) at (2, 4);
    \draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-14,-14) grid[step=2cm] (14,14);
    
    \foreach \x in {-7,-6,...,7}{% Two indices running over each
        \foreach \y in {-7,-6,...,7}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
            \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (4*\x, 4*\x + 2*\y) {};
                % Places a dot at those points
        }
    }
        
    %\draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    %    -- (Bthree) node [above, right] {$b_3$};
    \fill[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.3, draw=black] (4,2) ellipse (3cm and 1.75cm);
    \end{scope}
    
    \spy on (0,0) in node at (2,6);
    \spy on ({.45*4},0) in node at (2,6);
    \spy on (0,{.45*2}) in node at (2,6);
    \spy on ({.45*4},{.45*2}) in node at (2,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To make the spy image larger, you can use the option `magnification`. But note that since you are not spying with a regular circle or square, you need to state the height and width of the spy image explicitly:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45, spy using overlays={black!0, height={2*0.45*4cm}, width={2*0.45*8cm}, anchor=south west, magnification=2}]
    \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-3,0);
    \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (10,0);
    \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2);
    \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,10);
    
    \draw [thin, black,-latex] (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax);% Draw x axis
    \draw [thin, black,-latex] (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax);% Draw y axis
    
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0, 0) rectangle (8cm,4cm);
    \coordinate (Bone) at (0,2);
    \coordinate (Btwo) at (4,2);
    %\coordinate (Bthree) at (2, 4);
    \draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-14,-14) grid[step=2cm] (14,14);
    
    \foreach \x in {-7,-6,...,7}{% Two indices running over each
        \foreach \y in {-7,-6,...,7}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
            \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (4*\x, 4*\x + 2*\y) {};
                % Places a dot at those points
        }
    }
        
    %\draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    %    -- (Bthree) node [above, right] {$b_3$};
    \fill[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.3, draw=black] (4,2) ellipse (3cm and 1.75cm);
    \end{scope}
    
    \spy on (0,0) in node at (2,6);
    \spy on ({.45*4},0) in node at (2,6);
    \spy on (0,{.45*2}) in node at (2,6);
    \spy on ({.45*4},{.45*2}) in node at (2,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i resize the spy image so that it look bigger? I am not very familiar with spy

Comment: @haxerl See my edit. I am not sure, is this what you mean? Or do you want to spy on a larger area?

Comment: thank you the edit is just what i want