# Watercolor in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

Is it possible to fill a shape with a coloring that looks like watercolor like in this image

[image]

using tikz or pgfplots?

*Src: http://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/07/29/representable-functors/*

Comment: This is definitely a case where I'd use something like Inkscape or Photoshop to make the watercolor background and *then* include it in the doc with TikZ/etc.

Comment: related: [Random ink blotches from tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121388/random-ink-blotches-from-tikz)

Comment: Coffee is mostly water. So would coffee stains count as watercolour?

Answer (score 2):

There are some "cheap" way to generate complex pictures. But as Ti*k*Z manual says,

> These are the least portable of all and they put the heaviest burden of the renderer.
>   They are slow and, possibly, will not print correctly!

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading{watercolor}{\pgfpoint{-25bp}{-25bp}}{\pgfpoint{25bp}{25bp}}{}{
    -0.1 0.651
    exch 4 2 roll
    12.5 div exch 12.5 div 1 index dup mul add
    true
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {dup dup mul 2 index dup mul sub 3 index add 3 1 roll 2 mul mul 3 index add exch 2 copy dup mul exch dup mul add 4 le}{false}ifelse
    {0 0 0}{1 1 1}ifelse
}
\tikz{\shade[shading=watercolor](-10,-10)rectangle(10,10);}
\end{document}
```

### Note

I am not claiming that this looks like a watercolor. Nor did I try to achieve that. I am dumb at art. So the rest is your job.

### Note 2

The principle of watercolor is that pigment molecules run on the canvas and slow down as time passes. Therefore the best way to simulate watercolor is perhaps to solve a PDE numerically. This is not allowed in `\pgfdeclarefunctionalshading`. But it worth a try once you have a 2D array.